# Swiftlint overriding project settings related to SPM

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, swiftlint

I am running into a strange behavior with swiftlint autocorrect. My project uses a library imported through SPM. But when I run the linter, it changes settings like the following

```
B4621A7323D0A90F00545ADE /* LibraryName in Frameworks */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; productRef = B4621A7223D0A90F00545ADE /* LibraryName */; };

files = (
    B4621A7323D0A90F00545ADE /* LibraryName in Frameworks */,

packageProductDependencies = (
    B4621A7223D0A90F00545ADE /* LibraryName */,

packageReferences = (
    B4621A7123D0A90F00545ADE /* XCRemoteSwiftPackageReference "library-name" */,
```

to something like this

```
B4621A7323D0A90F00545ADE /* BuildFile in Frameworks */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; productRef = B4621A7223D0A90F00545ADE /* SwiftPackageProductDependency */; };

files = (
    B4621A7323D0A90F00545ADE /* BuildFile in Frameworks */,

packageProductDependencies = (
    B4621A7223D0A90F00545ADE /* SwiftPackageProductDependency */,

packageReferences = (
    B4621A7123D0A90F00545ADE /* RemoteSwiftPackageReference */,
```

It basically removes all references to the actual library and replaces them with some generic things. I tried adding two different libraries and it did the same to both libraries.

Any idea what might be going on and how I can fix it?

Comment: I got the same issue, but I'm not using SwiftLint autocorrect. Are you using the command from the Xcode menu `File > Swift Packages > Resolve Package Versions`? Maybe that's connected.

Comment: I have the same issue when running [this fastlane plugin](https://github.com/SiarheiFedartsou/fastlane-plugin-versioning). Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to SwiftLint autocorrect nor any fastlane plugin as stated in other comments. As far as I can tell, for now, this is an Xcode bug.